# Что делает функция change в С++

Tags: c++

Как понял, она изменяет что-то. Хотелось бы наглядный пример работы этой функции увидеть и понять, зачем эта функция нужна

Comment: Что-то я такую не припоминаю... Это точно из **языка** C?

Comment: Да, я ошибся, скорее всего, это не Си, а С++

Comment: Расскажите, в каком примере вы её видели? Может вы имели ввиду `replace`?

Comment: double randRange(double min, double max)
{
double r = (double)rand() / 32767.0;

return min + r * (max - min);
}

if (randRange(0.0, 100.0) < сhange)
dosmth();

Comment: В этом контексте `change` больше на переменную похожа чем на функцию. По смыслу, так вообще есть подозрение, что не `change`, а `chance`.

Comment: Тоже думал, что вместо `change` должна быть по логике константа, характеризующая шанс события. Однако, шанс события нестационарен. Он зависит от многих внешних факторов. Скорее всего функция `change` считывает изменения внешней информации и преобразует переменную, характеризующую шанс, по заданному алгоритму в число, характеризующее шанс условного события, т.е. события, зависяшего от некоторых других событий. Но это догадки. А догадки мне не нужны.

Comment: Т.к. функция не стандартная, кроме догадок, вряд ли, что можно предложить (и если это все таки ф-ия, пропущены круглые скобки в месте вызова).

Answer (score 4):

Первая функция - получение случайного значения между `min` и `max`. Заметим, *некорректное* - потому что надо использовать не 32767.0, а стандартную константу `RAND_MAX`.

```
double randRange(double min, double max) 
{ 
    double r = (double)rand() / 32767.0; 
    return min + r * (max - min); 
}
```

Тут `dosmth()` выполняется, если значение **переменной** `change` больше очередного случайного числа от 0 до 100.

```
if (randRange(0.0, 100.0) < сhange) dosmth();
```

`change` - переменная, в крайнем случае макрос, потому что как функция она бы записывалась как `change()`.

Вопрос абсолютно бессмысленен, потому что в **языке** (что C, что C++) такой функции нет. Это кем-то написанный код, и обращаться надо к его автору. Это все равно, что требовать от словаря пояснений, что означает и как пишется придуманное ребенком какое-нибудь "бяка-закаляка"...

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я понял.